# Using Pyinstaller to package Scrapy Project with Gooey on Mac OS

Tags: python, macos, scrapy, pyinstaller

I have a Scrapy project with a Gooey frontend and I want to package it in a distributable for macOS. I have a `runner.py` invocation point to run the crawler but packing it for MacOs seems difficult. I made a `build.spec` for PyInstaller on windows (**which works fine**) but the `build.spec` for Mac doesn't seem to package everything. It does create a execuble but it doesn't work.
Here is the `spec` file:

```
import gooey
gooey_root = os.path.dirname(gooey.__file__)
gooey_languages = Tree(os.path.join(gooey_root, 'languages'), prefix = 'gooey/languages')
gooey_images = Tree(os.path.join(gooey_root, 'images'), prefix = 'gooey/images')
a = Analysis(scripts=['runner.py'],
             pathex=['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib'],
             binaries=[('/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Tk', 'tk'),
               ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Tcl', 'tcl')],
             hiddenimports=['SearchEngineScrapy.spiders.searchenginespider'],
             hookspath=['hooks/'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             datas=[('SearchEngineScrapy/spiders','./spiders'), ('SearchEngineScrapy/utils','./utils'),
                    ('SearchEngineScrapy/settings.py','./settings.py'), ('SearchEngineScrapy/items.py','./items.py'),
                    ('SearchEngineScrapy/middlewares.py','./middlewares.py'), ('SearchEngineScrapy/pipelines.py','./pipelines.py'),
                    ('scrapy.cfg','.')
                   ]
             )
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.binaries, a.zipped_data)

options = [('u', None, 'OPTION'), ('v', None, 'OPTION'), ('w', None, 'OPTION')]

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          options,
          gooey_languages, # Add them in to collected files
          gooey_images, # Same here.
          name='SearchEngineScrapy',
          debug=True,
          strip=None,
          upx=False,
          console=False,
          windowed=True)
```

Please let me know what I am missing here. What should I add to make it a working application distribution.

Comment: What's missing is the information about what specifically "doesn't seem to work".

Comment: sorry, added in question. The package is created successfully but it doesn't work. I don't know how to package everything.

Comment: Do you get a specific error?

Comment: No specific error. The app doesn't start. Many modules are missing.

Comment: Can you include the output that supports that statement? (“Many modules are missing”) Do you get any warning when building the executable?